# Deploying an application that uses both VUE and Flask (Python)

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, deployment

Currently my project uses Flask as a backend and VUE as the frontend. For things to work correctly, I need to both run my Flask instance and VUE instance at the same time. Is this common practice? I have never deployed a build before and needing to have two "servers" / instance working at the same thing is a bit worrying to me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two servers in most cases. To host most SPAs you actually need a place to save them that can be exposed via a URL. In the past, I have used things like [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/).

You can reuse your backend server to host static front-end content.
You can do this a few ways actually:

- Set up a port for each
- Set up one or the other as a fallback

So for example you could have your API exposed at 8080 and your frontend on 5000. Or you could do something like this (Assuming Nginx)

Here is an example of the above:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {{server_name}};

    location /api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:{{path_to_backend}};
    }

  location / {
    root {{path_to_spa}};
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```